# Grails 2.2.4 JAXRS inheritance

Tags: grails, jax-rs

I have an interface outside my grails-app as below

```
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public interface EligibilityCDSService {


    @Path("/pushRawData")
    @POST
    public boolean pushRawData(final Eligibility e);
}
```

Inside my grails app under resources or src (I have tried both), I have the following implementing class

```
class MyService  implements  EligibilityCDSService{

    @Override
    public boolean pushRawData(Eligibility e){
        e.toString()
    }
}
```

When I try to access **localhost:8080/pushRawData** I get **404**

Additional Info (If required): I have my grails app converted as maven and though I am not using any jaxrs annotations inside my grails app, yet I have added dependency for grails jaxrs plugin version 0.8 in my pom.xml

Please help what am I missing.

Comment: Try putting `@Path("/")` on `MyService`

Answer (score 0):

By Default jaxrs plugin accepts url mapping only **/api**

I had to update Config.groovy the below property to accept different url paths

**org.grails.jaxrs.url.mappings=['/','/api']**